# Finding MLE of a single sample from discrete distribution

Tags: probability-theory, estimation

I'm really stuck with this problem:

Suppose a single sample $X$ is taken from a discrete distribution with pmf given by

$p(x;\theta) = \left\{\begin{array}{lcc}\frac{1+\theta}{12}&\mbox{if}&x=0\\
\frac{2\theta}{12}&\mbox{if}&x=1\\
\frac{11-3\theta}{12}&\mbox{if}&x=2\\
\end{array}\right.$

where $\theta = \{1,2\}$. Give the MLE of $\theta$ based from $x$.

From what I understand, getting $L(\theta)$ means multiplying the pmf of each $x$. I ended up with

$L(\theta) = (\frac{1+\theta}{12})(\frac{2\theta}{12})(\frac{11-3\theta}{12})$

Then taking the $ln$...

$lnL(\theta) = ln(1+\theta) + ln(2\theta) + ln(11-3\theta) - 3ln(12)$

I was proceeding to differentiating but I feel that the equation must have an $x$ in it. I can't figure out though. I kinda sure I have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=0$ then $p(0,1)=1/6$ and $p(0,2)=1/4$. So given the value of $x$ the MLE would be $\theta=2$ as this is more likely. Just repeat for the other values of $x$.

The general case is as below. If there are $n_i$ cases of $x=i$, then $log_L(\theta)= n_0*Log(1+\theta)+ n_1*Log(2\theta) + n_2*Log(11-3 \theta)$. If $\theta$ was continuous you would differentiate this and solve. However all you need to do is feed in $\theta=1$ and $\theta=2$ and see which is largest.

Comment: Thank you so much for the input. Following this I got $x = \{0,1\}$ $\theta MLE = 2$ and $x = \{2\}$ $\theta MLE = 1$. 

Did I get that right? Can you also explain why the $L(\theta)$ formula is not used? I'm kinda confused when and when not to use $L(\theta)$ method. Is there a general rule I should be looking for?

Comment: Your answer is correct.  You can always use $L(\theta)$ or its log. In essence this is what I did in the first paragraph although this was not especially obvious. If you put say $n_0=1$ and $n_1=n_2=0$ and look to maximize $LogL$ by trying different values of theta you will get the same answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it better now!